# Using OTA to intercept Control+Click

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to create a new shortcut in Delphi, where when I Control+Alt+Click in a "type" it send me to it's declaration.

The same as it does when I Control+Click (Find Declaration) it. The reason I'm doing it, it's because I want to add a logic in it's "Find Declaration".

My idea so far is to intercept the Find Declaration, check if Alt is on, if it's send to my on implementation otherwise send it to the regular flow.

Do you know how  to do it using OTA ?